# Javascript drop down works in jsfiddle but not in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am trying to get minutes in drop down using javascript.
in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reecreations/gj9qta3q/1/) it works however when I use it in my page it doesn't.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>

        <script type="text\javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                var minutes = [],
                select = document.getElementById( 'minutes' );
                for( minutes=1;minutes<=59;minutes++ ) {
                    select.add( new Option(minutes) );
                };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
        <select id="minutes"></select>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a js/jquery.js wherever it is you're hosting your page?

Comment: who is calling `myFunction`

Comment: Yes, I do have and working fine for other pages. Infact I tried to use jquery cdn also but still the same problem. It just shows blank dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash direction is wrong. Should be `text/javascript` not `text\javascript`

Also move the contents of the function to the global scope.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved it by doing suggested changes. Here is my corrected code `<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getminutes() {
    var minutes = [],
    select = document.getElementById( 'minutes' );
    for( minutes=1;minutes<=59;minutes++ ) {
           select.add( new Option(minutes) );
       };
   }
 </script>
  <p>
  <select id="minutes" onclick="getminutes();"></select>
  </p>
 </body>
</html> `

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to wrap the code in `$(document.ready()` like below:
2. Also, you need to call myFunction, which I don't see.
3. Additionally, modify `<script type="text\javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           function myFunction() {
               var minutes = [],
               select = document.getElementById('minutes');
               for (minutes = 1; minutes <= 59; minutes++) {
                   select.add(new Option(minutes));
               };
           }
           myFunction();//<---Call here
       });
   ```